# go.sum are different when using go mod vendor/download

Tags: go

I have a problem with the usage of commands `go mod vendor` and `go mod download` in a go module.

When I'm using `go mod vendor`, the generated go.sum has extra-lines. E.g, when I'm using `go mod download`, the `go.sum` contains:

```
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.1/go.mod h1:VGX0DQ3Q6kWi7AoAeZDth3/j3BFtOZR5XLFGgcrjCOs=
```

However if I remove the `go.sum` and run `go mod vendor`, I have 2 lines:

```
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.1 h1:6MnRN8NT7+YBpUIWxHtefFZOKTAPgGjpQSxqLNn0+qY=
github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.1/go.mod h1:VGX0DQ3Q6kWi7AoAeZDth3/j3BFtOZR5XLFGgcrjCOs=
```

This is problematic because if I commit the `go.sum` after running `go mod vendor`, any further `go mod download` (which may be used by someone else or in CI) will not work because of mismatching hashes which lead to a security issue.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the usage of `go mod vendor` and `go mod download`? Why would they produce different hashes in the `go.sum`?

Here is the kind of error which instantly happens:

```
verifying xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@v0.1.0: checksum mismatch
     downloaded: h1:tIKKCv/bUyBNvVsB6YLo0Ds9ZFdGJ0FKkFun22nwvCI=
     go.sum:     h1:qta5K5jjJg+TnsD76tcFK7Bjf402WP9MIbPsJGU11Ms=

SECURITY ERROR
This download does NOT match an earlier download recorded in go.sum.
The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
have intercepted the download attempt.
```

(Note: I replaced the name of the package by xxx because it carries my company name)

Comment: But the hashes are not different. I don't understand the problem. Can you add the output for a failing command to the question?

Comment: "after running go mod vendor, any further go mod download" there is no need to "go mod download" if the dependencies are vendored. You _either_ vendor (in which case you do not need go mod download) _or_ you download your dependencies, not both.

Comment: @Peter I added details on the error

Comment: @Volker The problem about this is that in local I'm developing using vendors for auto-completion. Then CI creates a docker image with go mod download inside, which fails. I know that the easy way is to use only one or the other but this is not the point of my question

Comment: Then do not commit your vendored stuff, neither the vendored folder nor your  go.mod. Also: auto-completions works fine with modules and doesn't  need vendoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually that the git repository was using git-lfs, but git-lfs was not available on either client or server side, which lead to incoherent hashes when calculated with and without git-lfs.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `go mod download` did not add `go.sum` entries for the downloaded modules was arguably a bug, and it will be fixed in the upcoming Go 1.16 release (see https://golang.org/issue/41341).

Comment: The `SECURITY ERROR` you are seeing likely indicates that someone at some point moved the `v0.1.0` tag on the corresponding repository. That will need to be resolved separately — perhaps by getting the owner of that repository to issue a corrected `v0.1.1` tag and updating your dependencies to use that.

The complete `go.sum` file should be committed to version control.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you just can delete the `go.sum` file and regenerate it.

so

```
rm go.sum
go mod tidy
```