# Get autocompletion with go.sum generated by go mod download

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when I generate my go.sum using `go mod download`, I loose the autocompletion in VS Code.

I get it back if I generate it using `go mod vendor`, which generates different hashes in the go.sum (see a previous question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007082/go-sum-are-different-when-using-go-mod-vendor-download?noredirect=1#comment116711512_66007082)).

However, I really would like always to have the go.sum version generated by `go mod download` instead of the other version, because otherwise I'm having hash verification issues in my CI system because of a divergence between expected and generated go.sum.

When I generate my `go.sum` with `go mod download`, gopls shows the following error :

```
Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.sum needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error
```

I guess this is because it needs to rewrite the go.sum because it runs a `go mod vendor` in background.

Is there some configuration I can use to have autocompletion while not forcing `go.sum` modification by `go mod vendor`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "PROBLEMS" section? When the go.sum mismatch is detected, the issue should be presented in the corresponding `go.mod` file along with the desired fix. Open the `go.mod` file, and select one of the quickfixes or code lenses  suggested (either `go mod tidy` or `update go.sum` entry).